# Exposing model method with Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am currently working on implementing an API into my Django project and Tastypie seemed like it would be most suitable.

What I can't seem to work out is how to expose a function within my model using Tastypie.

For example, I have this model:

```
class game(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField("ID", primary_key=True, editable=False)
    ip_address = models.OneToOneField(IPAddress, verbose_name="IP Address")
    port = models.CharField("Port", max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField("Game Name", max_length=100)
    ram = models.IntegerField("RAM (mb)", max_length=10)
    node = models.ForeignKey(node)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    config = models.ForeignKey(Config)
    mysqlserver = models.ForeignKey(MySQLserver)
    mysqlenabled = models.BooleanField("MySQL Created?")
    suspended = models.BooleanField("Suspended")
```

And within this model, I have functions such as this:

```
def start(self):
    config = Config.objects.get(pk=self.config.id)
    cmds = config.startcmds
    game = config.gametype
    parsedcmds = self.replace_variables(cmds)

    client = phPanel.jelly.jelly.zmqclient(self.ip_address.address)
    data = {'user':self.generate_username(), 'method':'start_server', 'id':self.id, 'memory':self.ram, 'ip':self.ip_address.address,
            'port':self.port, 'startcmds':parsedcmds, 'game':game}

    result = client.send(data)
    return result
```

which I would like to expose through the API using tastypie.

I've looked through the documentation and the cookbook but I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You probably want to have a look at: https://github.com/gati/tastypie-model-method

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Within your Game-Resource, you can always prepend new urls that can expose methods. For example (Edited according to the comment by @BigglesZX):

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash

class GameResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
         queryset = Game.objects.all()
         resource_name = 'store'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        """ Add the following array of urls to the GameResource base urls """
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/start%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('start'), name="api_game_start"),
        ]

    def start(self, request, **kwargs):
         """ proxy for the game.start method """  

         # you can do a method check to avoid bad requests
         self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])

         # create a basic bundle object for self.get_cached_obj_get.
         basic_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)

         # using the primary key defined in the url, obtain the game
         game = self.cached_obj_get(
             bundle=basic_bundle,
             **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

         # Return what the method output, tastypie will handle the serialization
         return self.create_response(request, game.start())
```

So now you can call this method using the following uri "/game/[pk]/start/"
So "/game/1/start/" will call the start method of game with pk = 1

Comment: The signature for the `cached_obj_get` function has changed as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15159600/258794

Comment: You are right @BigglesZX I updated my answer to reflect the latest version of tastypie.

Comment: how would you do with tastypie 0.9.11 ? I don't find any prepend_urls function in this version :/

Comment: @aRkadeFR In 0.9.11 the official way was using the method "override_urls", it was deprecated in favor of "prepend_urls". You can find the documentation here: https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/resources.html#override-urls