# Tastypie Nested Resources - cached_obj_get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, tastypie

I'm trying to use the example here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources

for some reason i get:

> cached_obj_get() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

even though i clearly call it with 2 arguments (exactly like in the aforementioned example.
this is my code:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/feed%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_feed'), name="api_get_feed"),
]

def get_feed(self, request, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = self.cached_obj_get(request=request, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs)) 
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpGone()
    except MultipleObjectsReturned:
        return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")

    feed_resource = FeedItemResource()
    return feed_resource.get_list(request, p_id=obj.id)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion - there was an [API change to improve authorization](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/commit/d850758b088761a00f60a474f5b2d683dc1ec3c0) which changed the signature for [`cached_obj_get`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.12/tastypie/resources.py#L1103) from:

```
def cached_obj_get(self, request=None, **kwargs):
```

to

```
def cached_obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs):
```

This change is consistent going forward – and if you needed the `request` object, it's available as `bundle.request` – but obviously the documentation needs to be updated.

You can build a bundle object with:

```
basic_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)
```

then use it as an argument to `cached_obj_get` (see [`Resource.get_detail` source code](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.12/tastypie/resources.py#L1276) as an example):

```
obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=basic_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
```

The other confusing aspect if you're not familiar with Python's object model is that methods always receive at least one argument because the first positional argument is always the [object instance or `self`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) and keyword arguments aren't included in that count so “1 given” means that the method only received the `self` positional argument when it was expecting `self` and `bundle`.

Comment: Thanks to David R. for explaining how to build a bundle & adding an example!

Comment: I stumbled upon this answer while searching for same error message for obj_get(). This answer holds true obj_get() as well