# Modify data before saving Django-tastypie

Tags: django, rest, django-models, tastypie

I am using `Django-Tastypie` to create REST APIs for my Django model. My test User model has following fields in it.

```
user_id       models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user_name     models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
user_rating   models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here, I want to write an API that on request, increments user's rating every time by 1. Currently I am maintaining a cumulative rating and I know how we can overwrite rating but Not sure about how we can modify the data before insert so that Next value is 1 more than previous one.

I already went through Django-Tasypie documentation to check if there is any direct solution and tried `prepend_url` to modify request but Not sure how we can fetch current rating and update it.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?
What do you mean: "on request, increments user's rating every time by 1"?
Did you mean, every time you update the user resource you update a user_rating by 1 or every time you specifically request to update user_rating by 1.

Comment: @ge7600 e.g. We can say it's kind of feature like stackoverflow has where for each question/answer stackoverflow maintains an upvote count and when a new user comes and does upvote, the count gets incremented by one. Am I clear now in what I meant?

Answer (score 0):

OK.
You meant that if you update resource1 you update the "user_rating" field of the user resource.
You can override the django model save method of model1 that is associated with resource1.

```
    class Model1(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey('User')
        id = models.BigIntegerField()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255L)
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'table1'
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Model1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.user.user_rating += 1
            self.user.save()
```

Comment: Hi ge7600, thanks for your reply. The solution looks good but this will increment the user rating by one for all updates which is Not something that the application needs. It should update only this field without affecting others.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into a few more [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085865/exposing-model-method-with-tastypie), I was able to figure out how we can solve this using `prepend_url`. So, I am just going to write what worked for me and hoping that It'll be useful to others as well.

This is how my `UserResource` look like.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        Return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<user_id>\w[\w/-]*)/upvote%s$" %
                (Self. _meta. resource_name, trailing_slash ()),
                self.wrap_view('upvote_user'), name="api_user_upvote"),
        ]

    def upvote_user(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        self.is_authenticated(request)
        self.throttle_check(request)

        try:
            basic_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)
            obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=basic_bundle,
                                      **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpGone()
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")

        user_manager_obj = UserManager()
        return self.create_response(request, user_manager_obj.upvote_user(obj.user_id))
```

and wrote one more method in my `UserManager` class to perform upvote operation on `User` model.

```
def upvote_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        user.user_rating += 1
        user.save()
    except:
        # Handle Exception
        return False

    return True
```

This shows how we can use `prepend_url` to modify the data before saving it using models and I think its much more powerful than this. Please share If you think there is any better solution to achieve same.

Thanks