# Accessing Django Model Methods Through TastyPie

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I am trying to access a purchase method that I have written inside my item model through a TastyPie API. Here is the method:

```
def purchase(self, buyer):
    sold = False
    seller = self.seller
    if self.for_sale != False:
        if seller != buyer:
            self.for_sale = False
            sold =  True
    return sold
```

I have confirmed that this function works in the shell. Here is the purchase function I have written in the resource to call my model method:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/purchase%s$' % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('purchase'), name = 'api_item_purchase'),
    ]

def purchase(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed = ['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))


    item_id = data.get('item_id', '')
    print item_id
    buyer = request.user
    print buyer
    item = Item.objects.get(pk = item_id)
    print item

    return self.create_response(request, item.purchase(buyer))
```

I'm basing this off of another stack that I found:

[Exposing model method with Tastypie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085865/exposing-model-method-with-tastypie)

but it doesn't seem to be working, I get 200 server ok in addition to "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set" but the method never actually gets called.

Comment: From the error message you show, looks like your problem is with the way you're making the request in the first place. Are you posting a well formed json object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I haven't sent any JSON.

Comment: The purchase url is receiving post requests, and it deserializes the body expecting json format. If you are not posting json data, how are you accessing that url? Going into it in the browser would be performing a "get" which you're not allowing for that url.

Comment: Found a solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085865/exposing-model-method-with-tastypie